# Why is the function $ e^{t^2} $ is non-integrable?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, exponential-function

In my book, it's written that $e^{t^2}$ is non-integrable, but I don't understand this. Isn't integration just the area under the curve? And the graph of $e^{t^2}$ can also be made; hence, we can also find the area under it.
Please help me out.

Comment: It probably means that its integral cannot be expressed in terms of [elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function).  What book are you reading?

Comment: Statements of that form mean that "the indefinite integral of the given function can not be expressed using standard functions in standard ways", not that the indefinite integral does not exist.

Comment: I think your book refers to the possibility of finding an antiderivative (a function $F(x)$ such that $F'(x)=e^{x^2}$ in terms of national functions, exponentials, logarithms and trig-functions) This is the subject of diferential algebra.  A result by [Liouville](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(differential_algebra)) summarizes when certain functions have antiderivatives. This ay be a little advanced for you at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

It is definitely integrable

However if you are concerned whether a proper anti derivative(comprised of elementary functions only) exist or not, then sorry that’s not possible in this case.

Why so ?

The answer lies here : Liouville's theorem, which simply says that certain elementary functions do not have an elementary function as their antiderivatives

Answer (score 0):

The function is integrable on any given finite interval $[a,b]$, but it's not integrable over the whole real line -- the 'area under the graph' would be infinite.

The book shouldn't be intending the following, but if someone said in casual conversation that it's "not integrable", they might mean that there is no closed form for the indefinite integral in terms of elementary functions. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonelementary_integral for more information about that.